# Jboss Admin console not showing any messaging option under subsystems

Tags: java, switchyard, jboss-eap-7

In Windows OS:

I have tried starting jboss server with out using standalone-full-*.xml files ,in this case admin console not showing any messaging option under subsystems.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?

Answer (score 2):

The `messaging-activemq` subsystem requires the `org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq` extension, which is not included in standard `standalone.xml` and `standalone-ha.xml` configurations included in the WildFly distribution.

It is, however, included with the `standalone-full.xml` and `standalone-full-ha.xml` configurations.

You can add the extension to a configuration without it either by adding an `<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>` element to the xml or by using the following CLI operation:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /]/extension=org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq:add
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it:

```
1) command prompt
2) UI

1)Command Prompt:
First start the server

Go to jboss-cli.sh and enter the following commands:
i) connect
ii)  jms-queue add --queue-address=test queue --entries=java:/jms/queue/test
iii) You can check the configuration is done in standalone or standalone-full.xml (whatever conf file you are using), go to that file and search for your queue name

2) UI (management console)
1)Start the server and goto localhost:8080 , enter username and pass
2) Goto Configuration - subsystem - messaging and click on add
```

Answer (score 0):

EAP 7.0 server will come with embedded ActiveMQ server.

If your using windows : start Jboss Eap 7.0 server using command prompt.
use -full or full-ha.xml files for starting server from CMD.

$  jboss-eap-7.0\bin>standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml

After starting server. go to browser hit this url.
http://127.0.0.1:9990/

Click on Configuration tab

-->Subsystems --> "Messaging - ActiveMQ"

-->default-->Queues/Topics

Here you can add or remove queue

Answer (score 0):

If you create queue with JNDI "java:/jms/queue/test" it will be accessible only for invm connection factories. To access it remotely i.e from remote machines, you need to mark it exported like "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"